# onSnapshot on document Firebase React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to have real time data using `onSnapshot` function. The problem is that I want to have it on specific document which ID I have got. I tried this :

```
const getMembers = () => {
  db.collection('wydarzenie').doc(props.event_id).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.docData())
  })
}
```

but I got error that `snapshot.docData` is not a function

And I also tried this :

```
const getMembers = () => {
    db.collection('wydarzenie').where('id' , '==', props.event_id).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.docChanges())
    })}
```

But my document doesn't contain his id in himself...

I wanted to have real time listener on array - `uczestnicy` - in `wydarzenie` collection, but I don't have idea how to do it.
My data base looks like :
[image: photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you listen to a single document, the parameter to your callback is a `DocumentSnapshot`. To get its data, you call `data()` on it.

So:

```
const getMembers = () => {
  db.collection('wydarzenie').doc(props.event_id).onSnapshot(doc => {
    console.log(doc.data())
  })
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listening for realtime updates to a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web).

Comment: I have one more question. If I write code like this : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dawn-fpiwq?file=/src/App.js
How onSnapshot works ? When something in my document would change, my component will re-render ? Or only getMembers() function would run ?